# ArangoDB: is it possible to 'fake' edges in a graph traversal?

Tags: graph, arangodb

I've got a complex graph. I am using a traversal (through ArangoJS) with also quite complex expanderFunction and traversalVisitor.

For this traversal, I'd like to know if it is possible to create dynamic relations (or *fake* relations) between some nodes in my graph): That is, based on some attributes in a vertex,  let the traversal pursue the graph exploration as if there was an edge between the current vertex and another one.

I've tried to trick the *expander* function, pushing a fake edge ( from the current vertex to another not related one in the graph) into the traversal data structures, something like:

```
if (complex_criteria(vertex)) {
    var unconnectedVertexId = ... 
    var unconnectedVertex = someCollection.document(unconnectedVertexId);
    connected.push({ edge:{_id:'newId', _from:vertex._id, _to:unconnectedVertex._id}, vertex: unconnectedVertex });
}
..
return connected;
```

This did not work. ( traversal options were: *direction: 'outbound', strategy: "depthfirst"* )

Any better idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think there is a slight mistake in you code:

```
if (complex_criteria(vertex)) {
    var unconnectedVertexId = ... 
    var unconnectedVertex = someCollection.document(unconnectedVertexId);
    connected.push({ edge:{_id:'newId', _from:vertex._id, _to:unconnectedVertex._id}, vertex: unconnectedVertex });
}
..
return connected;
```

the "fake-edge" `_to` has to point to `unconnectedVertex._id`, not the object itself.
Can you check if this fixes the problem already?

Comment: _id: this was already in my test case. A mistake while changing the variable names above for clarity. I've corrected the question.  Do you know where in the ArangoDB code I could see how the *connected* data structure from the expander is used afterwards ? I think there may be some limitations in the way this data structure is used afterwards..( like maybe trying to get the edge from an not-existing edge id ?)  Could help..  Cheers

Comment: The file you are looking for is `js/common/modules/@arangodb/graph/traversal.js` in current devel branch or `js/common/modules/org/arangodb/graph/traversal.js` there are `3` calls to `config.expander` which are the relevant places.

From what i see there is that the edge is not validated after "expander" by the built in functions. Maybe the `_id` is somewhere evaluated internally so make sure that it at least looks correct. The unconnected vertex is validated and if the id is not known to arango unconnectedVertex will be null and might cause the trouble.

Comment: I've suppressed the  'direction' attribute from the traversal options. (The documentation is currently unclear about this, stating that   'expander must be set if direction attribute is not set' )

Comment: Does the explanation answer your question? If yes, can you mark it accepted? if not, whats missing?